# Find a simple sequence asymptotic to $\sin{(e\ \pi\ n)}$ when $n$ goes to infinity.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

(*Call two sequences $u_n$ and $v_n$ "equivalent" if* $\ \lim_{n\to\infty} u_n/v_n =1$.)

Using that $e=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty {1}{k!}$, find a simple sequence equivalent to $u_n=\sin{(e\pi n)}$ when $n$ goes to infinity.

**My solution so far:** At first I thought they wanted me to take a power series of a power series, i.e. write $e\pi n$ as a power series $\pi\ n \sum\limits_0^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$, and then take expand the sine of that with the sine Taylor series. But here we have $n$ going to infinity, and the sine series is centered at zero (or any finite number, but not infinity since it doesn't approach a limit at infinity).

What do you think they're looking for here?

Comment: Well $\sin(e \pi n)$ is a very simple-looking sequence to me, you would have to define 'simple'.

Comment: Could it be that the question asks about $u_n=\sin(e\pi n!)$?

Comment: @patrick I know, I agree, that's why this problem confuses me.

Comment: @andre I have no indication that there is a typo here.

Comment: If this is homework, you might have to ask the professor. If it isn't homework (possibly even if it is), do you have a source? Knowing where it comes from might shed some light on what it's asking for...

Comment: @user88203: The reasons I asked are (i) if it is indeed $n!$, then the series expansion is a very big hint and (ii) the fractional part of $ne$ is dense on the interval $(0,1)$, so there appears not much useful we can say.

Comment: Not clear that there can be such a sequence that is much less complicated, since $\sin e\pi n$ is dense in $[-1,1]$, so you'll need a sequence that is also pretty crazy. Andre's version of the question: $u_n=\sin (e\pi n!)$ yields a manageable answer, on the other hand.

Comment: It's from an old qualifier exam from NYU. Here is a scan: http://i.imgur.com/4YcfLJc.jpg?1

Comment: @andre What do you guys think about the convergence of the series mentioned in the next part of the scan?

Comment: @user88203: The terms do not have limit $0$.

Comment: @andre How do we know they do not have limit 0?

Comment: If $\beta$ is irrational, then the fractional values of $\beta n$ are dense in $[0,1]$. So if we let $en=k+\beta_n$, where $\beta_n$ is between $0$ and $1$, we have $\sin(e\pi n)=\sin(\pi k +\pi \beta_n)$. In absolute value this is $\sin(\pi\beta_n)$. Since $\beta_n$ is infinitely often "near" $1/2$, this means that infinitely often $\sin(e\pi n)$ has absolute value near $1$.

Answer (score 2):

One can rewrite $u_n$ as the imaginary part of an exponential: $$u_n=Im(e^{i\ e\ \pi\ n})$$ Next, you can expand the exponential in its taylor series (around 0): $$u_n=Im\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(i e \pi n)^k}{k!}\right)$$
The only imaginary parts of this summation is when k is odd:
$$
u_n=\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j\dfrac{(e\ \pi\ n)^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!}\\
$$
The $(-1)^j$ terms comes from the fact that for $k=1, 5, 9, ...$, $i^k=i$, and for $k=3, 7, 11, ...$, $i^k=-i$. This expression is the same as the original expression $\sin(e\pi n)$, in other words, one can let:
$$
v_n=\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j\dfrac{(e\pi n)^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!}\\
$$
which is equal to $u_n$. Thus this sequence is equivalent to $u_n$. The answer really depends on what you consider "**simple**".

Comment: You just computed the Taylor expansion of the sine function. I don't think that solves OP's issues.